# How to extend/modify the object in nodejs api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular-fullstack

i am using the angular-fullstack yeoman generator. created a schema for a Product, and a set of api crud operations. all works well. now in the get list operations, i don't want to receive all the fields, only a subset. like a select in sql. i would also wish to alter one value. instead of the price, i need price * 1.1 .
how to do that?
here is the code for the index method (returns list of products):

```
// Gets a list of Products
export function index(req, res) {
  Product.findAsync()
    .then(respondWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}


function respondWithResult(res, statusCode) {
  statusCode = statusCode || 200;
  return function(entity) {
    if (entity) {
      res.status(statusCode).json(entity);
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/), `.find()` takes two params, query and projection.

```
// params
Product.findAsync(query, projection)
```

You can use projection to "select" a subset of fields;

```
// example
Product.findAsync({}, { _id: 1, name: 1, description: 1 })

// result, only the three specified field will be returned
[
    { _id: 'abc123', name: 'Some name', description: 'Some description'},
    {...}
]
```

If you want to manipulate data I think you have to use the [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/)